# how to write getActiveFilters snippet in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

**In Magento 1.x snippets:-**

> $appliedFilters =
>   Mage::getSingleton(‘Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_State’)->getActiveFilters();

**(and)**

> $appliedFilters =
>   Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();

Please suggest me in magento 2 syntax for the above snippet?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this model: `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\State`

Try to use something like this:

```
protected $layerState;

public function __construct(
     ....
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\State $layerState
     ...
) {
    ....
     $this->layerState = $layerState;
    ....
}

public function getFilters()
{
    return $this->layerState->getFilters();
}
```

**EDIT**

Via object manager (not recommend)

```
$layerState = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\State');
$filters = $layerState->getFilters()
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and as well as Can you please suggest me using object manager?

Comment: @NagarajuKasa I've edited the answer. Try code above

Comment: hi @ІгорКлимчук https://prnt.sc/ir3crc i have used the above code in category list page but count shows zero

Answer (score 2):

Using Object Manager you can get it below ways , but that's not suitable !!

```
$getLayerState = ObjectManager::getInstance() >get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\State');

$filters = $getLayerState->getFilters()
```

Comment: Hi @Manthan Dave i have used u r magneto 2 snippet in the list.phtml and i tried to filter at layered navigation but count shows zero..

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ir3bq5 https://prnt.sc/ir3crc

Comment: Hi @Manhan Dave actually in magento 1 in the list.phtml i have used the above two snippets i got the desire result. Hence i would like to use the same concept in magento2 but no luck can you please suggest me thanks